# Publish().RefCount() not working?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a mildly 'expensive' calculation exposed through an IObservable property.

I want to protect it from being run multiple times if there are multiple subscribers, so I put a Publish().RefCount() behind it, but when I stick breakpoints in, I still see it getting called twice.

```
public IObservable<int> Property
{
    get { return _Source.Select(Expensive).Publish().RefCount(); }
}
```

Comment: by 'protect it from being run multiple times' what do you mean? (1) It should be executed only once and any further instruction to execute it must be ignored; or (2) at one time only one request should be handled, other requests (if any) should be (a) ignored, or (b) queued?

Answer (score 10):

It's only the *result* of `Publish().RefCount()` which is 'protected', not your source - as it stands, if you have multiple calls to your property, you will get multiple *independent* 'protected' observables - which will each subscribe *independently* to your source.

You need a backing field, which you can ensure will only be defined once:

```
private IObservable<int> _Property;
public IObservable<int> { get { return _Property; } }

//elsewhere:
_Property = _Source.Select(Expensive).Publish().RefCount()
```

(or alternatively)

```
public IObservable<int> { get; private set; }

//elsewhere:
_Property = _Source.Select(Expensive).Publish().RefCount()
```

Comment: @bradgonesurfing. Thanks for you edits. Sometimes feels like that guy is stalking me :)

Comment: This is any easy mistake to make. I'll have to do a quick code review of my latest RX code. I sure wish there was a set of good practices and patterns for using reactive extensions.